# Formtastic Belongs_to association and undefined method '_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, formtastic

In my application, there are users, lists, and books. Books belong_to lists, and lists have many books. What I want to do is to let the user create a new book and choose what list to place the book in within that form. I'm trying to use formtastic. Here is my code so far:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@book) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.input :list, :as => :select, :collection => List.find(:all, :order => "name ASC") %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Book title" %>
        <%= f.text_field :pages, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "# of pages" %>
        <%= f.text_field :author, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Author" %>

        <%= f.submit "Add book", class: "btn btn-default green-hover" %>

    <% end %>
```

The problem is that I get `undefined method 'books_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbe29898688>:0x007fbe29812da8>`. But I think my routes.rb file is correct:

```
resources :users do
  resources :lists, shallow: true do
    resources :books, shallow: true
  end
end
```

How come I'm getting this error?

**EDIT**

I changed my routes like so:

```
resources :users do
  resources :lists, shallow: true
end
resources :books
```

And now the form renders. But when I try to submit it, it doesn't work: `undefined local variable or method 'list' for #<BooksController:0x007fbe27cd6eb8>`. How can I access from the create action in the controller which list was picked?

**EDIT 2**

Here are the params that appear in the console after I submit a b`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OaMLlxWbhfBmyYuofNoLv3SfYmh44DzpB+fvHJDqojw60fKRsk2JoSn8LCDxkumyGsOVMGkepiPP2f+T9PDBqA==", "book"=>{"list_id"=>"1", "title"=>"Example", "pages"=>"100", "author"=>"Example"}, "commit"=>"Add book"}`

Comment: What does your controller look like? Do you have the instance variable of book in there looking something like @book = Book.new ?

Comment: @MilesUA Yes I do: `@book = current_user.books.build if logged_in?`

Answer (score 1):

I think your nested resources are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Best practice is to not nest resources more than one level deep (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting), but unless you have a specific reason to nest, just keep your resources un-nested, like this:

```
resources :users
resources :lists
resources :books
```

If you use un-nested routes like this, what you already have should just work. Formtastic is built to handle routes like this better. If you absolutely must have you resources nested, you're going to have to tell Formtastic which route to post to manually, like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@book, url: list_books_path({your_list_id_here}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: But this thing is that I don't know what the list id is. I want the user to be able to choose what list to put the book in, so I won't have any idea of what the list id is.

Comment: So I changed the routes, and the form appears. The only thing is that I need to be able to find the list from the controller. How can I get the list that the user selected from the controller?

Comment: Try using just `<%= f.input :list %>` without any options. Formtastic _might_ just figure out the relationship on its own and let the user pick from a list of `List`s. If that still doesn't work, try specifying that it as a `select` like this: `<%= f.input :list, :as => :select %>`
If the view is already rendering your picker just fine, post what your `params` are after you submit your form (you should see it in your logs, or in the terminal where you're running your `rails server`).

Comment: The view is rendering it fine. It's just that it gives me an error when I submit - updated the post to show results.

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much @spejamchr!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This is what I did:

1) Changed the routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :lists, shallow: true
end
resources :books
```

2) And if I want to access the id of the list chosen:

- Book params:

  ```
  def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :asin, :image_url, :pages, :list_id)
  end
  ```
- Finding the list:

  ```
  @list = List.find(book_params[:list_id])
  ```
- Creating the book:

  ```
  @book = @list.books.build(book_params)
  ```